# file to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3

Tags: ruby, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, compass

I have looked at the answers below and even after running `compass compile` I still get the error below.

I have installed all required gems but I keep getting the error.

What would be the best way to import fonts using the SASS workflow, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My Config.rb file

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
output_style = :compressed
```

My Gruntfile

```
/*jslint node: true */
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            options: {
                includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'compressed',
                    sourceMap: false,
                },
                files: {
                    'css/app.css': 'sass/app.scss'
                }
            }
        }, // sass

        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }
            } // dev
        }, //compass

        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                dateFormat: function(time) {
                    grunt.log.writeln('The watch finished in ' + time + 'ms at ' + (new Date()).toString());
                    grunt.log.writeln('Waiting for more changes...');
                } //date format function
            }, //options
            scripts: {
                files: ['*.js']
            }, // scripts
            //Live Reload of SASS
            sass: {
                files: 'sass/**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }, //sass
            css: {
                files: ['sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            },
            html: {
                files: ['*.html']
            }
        } //watch
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass', 'compass']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'watch']);
}
```

My Gems

```
actionpack (4.2.3)
actionview (4.2.3)
activesupport (4.2.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.5)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
chunky_png (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
compass-rails (2.0.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
ffi (1.9.10)
foundation (1.0.4)
fssm (0.2.10)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
loofah (2.0.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.7.0, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.3)
rake (0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sass (3.4.16)
sass-rails (5.0.1)
sprockets (2.12.4)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
susy (2.2.2)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Comment: You can't use both the `sass` command *and* the `compass` command.  When you run the `sass` command, you're explicitly *not using Compass*.

Comment: @cimmanon, should i remove the sass command or?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: I'm in a similar boat, removing it didn't solve the issue. Has the original author had any success?

Comment: I was able to resolve it, by using both the sass and compass command, @beta208, post the list of modules you are currently using.